# Correct usage for using loading cache with a <String, Boolean>?

Tags: java, guava

I have a cache of String, Boolean.:

```
Cache<String, Boolean> myCache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder().build();
```

My usage pattern is:

```
if (myCache.get("some-key") == null)  {
     // "some-key" not in cache, do stuff, then insert it
     myCache.put("some-key", Boolean.TRUE);
} 
else {
    // "some-key" already in cache
}
```

I am trying to change this so that it uses the alternative `get` method that takes a loader function `get(K key, Callable<? extends V> loader)`, to avoid the possibility that two threads both call `myCache.get("some-key") == null` and both enter the if block.

I am not sure if below is the correct way to do this?

I think `myCache.get("some-key", myCacheLoader)` will insert `some-key` into the cache if it is not present, but I also need to know if it was present or not, so I don't think the code below is correct.

```
CacheLoader<String, Boolean> myCacheLoader = createMyCacheLoader();
Cache<String, Boolean> myCache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder().build();

private static CacheLoader<String, Boolean> createMyCacheLoader(){
    return new CacheLoader<String, Boolean>(){
        @Override
        public Boolean load(final String key){
            return Boolean.TRUE;
        }
    };
}

if (!myCache.get("some-key", myCacheLoader))  { // I don't think this can ever be false?
    // I don't think if block will ever be entered?
    // How can I find out if an item isn't in the cache when using a loading cache?
} 
else {
    // "some-key" already in cache 
}
```

Comment: Take a look at the `build` method overload that accepts `CacheLoader`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build [`LoadingCache`](https://guava.dev/releases/30.0-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/LoadingCache.html) instead of `Cache` with the `CacheLoader` to achieve what you want. Please refer to [Guava CachesExplained wiki page](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained#from-a-cacheloader), specifically:

> A LoadingCache is a `Cache` built with an attached `CacheLoader`. (...) The canonical way to query a `LoadingCache` is with the method `get(K)`. This will either return an already cached value, or else use the cache's `CacheLoader` to atomically load a new value into the cache.

In your case:

```
    CacheLoader<String, Boolean> myCacheLoader = CacheLoader.from(key -> Boolean.TRUE);
    LoadingCache<String, Boolean> myCache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
            // optional config for LoadingCache
            .build(myCacheLoader);

    // or even inlined:
    LoadingCache<String, Boolean> myCache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
            // optional config for LoadingCache
            .build(CacheLoader.from(key -> Boolean.TRUE));

    try {
        final Boolean isValuePresent = myCache.get("some-key");
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        throw new UncheckedExecutionException(e.getCause()); // or whatever
    }

    final Boolean isAnotherValuePresent = myCache.getUnchecked("some-key-as-well");
```